# Monitoring Performance metrics more than one GCP environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

My requirement is to monitor performance metrics of GCP Environments. We have to monitor more than one GCP environment (Service Account). Now Problem is how can I set the all service Accounts JSON files in Environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS".

creating MetricServiceClient like below after setting JSON file in an environment variable
 MetricServiceClient client = MetricServiceClient.create()

Is there another way to create  MetricServiceClient using credentials.

Comment: Are you trying initiate connection to multiple GCP Project Stackdriver within the same program?

Comment: yes, you are right. My requirement is to get the performance metrics from more than one GCP  Project Stackdriver within the same program.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the StackDriver Workspace and add all the GCP Project you want to monitor to that workspace. Here is the detailed guide https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/guide.

By using a single Workspace for all GCP Project, you will have all the Metrics/Logging data in a single place and then you can use one set of credentials to access all GCP Project Monitoring data.

If the Single workspace is not a feasible option, then you can create a single GCP Service account and add StackDriver related permission from all the projects. Then you can use this service account to interact with Stackdriver metrics.

Note: Always try to use the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Hope this helps.